# How to bind data dynamically to baseChart in ng2-charts

Tags: html, angular, ng2-charts

I am unable to bind data to my graph. How to make it appear. Because when i put the numbers, the chart appears. But how to make the graph work when we use a variable to store the number.

code -

**component.ts**

```
    showData(){

    //code 

   this.entireSuccessResult = this.result1.length;

   this.entireErrorResult = this.result2.length;

       }


   public barChartOptionsEntire: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true
      };
     public barChartLabelsEntire: string[] = ['Success', 'Error', 
    'abcd','efgh'];
     public barChartTypeEntire = 'bar';
     public barChartLegendEntire = true;

     public barChartDataEntire: any[] = [
     { data: [this.entireSuccessResult,10,20,30], label: 'Success' },
      { data: [this.entireErrorResult,10,20], label: 'Error' }
       ];
```

**component.html**

```
    <div class="card-body" >
          <div class="chart-wrapper">

            <canvas baseChart class="chart"   
      [datasets]="barChartDataEntire"
               [labels]="barChartLabelsEntire"   
     [options]="barChartOptionsEntire"      
     [legend]="barChartLegendEntire"
              [chartType]="barChartTypeEntire"        
     (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" 
     (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can print your data on <pre> or <div> nodes, to see if their structure is correct: <div>{{barChartDataEntire[0].data[0]}}</div>  etc. Also, not sure if it matters, that the second entry has one less element in the data than the first one.

Comment: Thanks amy, using -> <div>{{barChartDataEntire[0].data[0]}}</div>  ..did work out. Here, no data doesn't shows up .Its blank . That means the variable here isn't working though it is globally declared. Have any ideas?